# How can I get the instance of a interface from Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-container

I registered

```
container.RegisterType<IService, MyService>();
```

I want to create a helper class similar to

```
public class MyHelper
{
    private IService _service;

    public void SomeMethod
    {
        _service.RunSomething();
    }
}
```

I really wish this _serivce just magically maps to MyService constructor and not be null, as I have no where to find an IService or Service instance anywhere else.

How can I make this _service self mapped according to Unity mapping?

Comment: Unity is a *dependency injection* container. So you need to actually inject the instance via constructor or setter injection. The way you're going about it now is that you hide a dependency on a concrete IService which is NOT what you want to be doing. If you're going to stick with the model you've got then you may as well just _service= new MyService();

Comment: @rism I actually did container.Resolve<IService>(). Is it better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still have to assign the injected `IService` to your instance. This is usually done via the constructor:

```
public class MyHelper {
    private readonly IService _service;

    public MyHelper(IService service) {
        _service = service;
    }

    public void SomeMethod() {
        // _service isn't null anymore
    }
}
```

Edit: looking at your comment I don't think you're using IoC correctly so I'm going to try to fill in some gaps. You don't want to create new instances of `MyHelper` beacuse whatever creates it will have to have knowledge of `IService` and any other dependencies `MyHelper` introduces. Instead, you can create a factory that handles creating new instances of `MyHelper` which will also handle its dependencies. This way, you can set up IoC to resolve dependencies on this factory.

```
public interface IInstanceFactory<out T> {
    T Create();
}

public class MyHelperFactory : IInstanceFactory<MyHelper> {
    private readonly Func<MyHelper> _myHelperFactory;

    public MyHelperFactory(Func<MyHelper> myHelperFactory) {
        _myHelperFactory = myHelperFactory;
    }

    public MyHelper Create() {
        return _myHelperFactory();
    }
}
```

So we now have a factory that stores a `Func` which is used to create an instance of `MyHelper`. All it's doing is executing the function that we will define in the IoC setup. All that function does is return a new instance of `MyHelper`.

Now we can set up IoC to handle everything else for us. So in your IoC setup you'd do the following (I don't know Unity so I'm going to show you using Autofac. Unity should be capable of doing everything I'm showing.)

Register the service:

```
container.RegisterType<MyService>().As<IService>();
```

Register the factory: (this is where the magic happens)

```
container.Resolve(b => {
    var service = b.Resolve<IService>();
    var myHelperFactory = new Func<MyHelper>(() => new MyHelper(service));

    return new MyHelperFactory(myHelperFactory);
}).As<IInstanceFactory<MyHelper>>();
```

Here we get an instance of `IService` which we already registered as `MyService`. Then we create a `Func<MyHelper>` who just creates a new instance of `MyHelper` and passes along the `IService` instance we just resolved. Lastly, we return a new `MyHelperFactory` and pass the `Func<MyHelper>` into the factory.

So lets say we have the class `Foo`. And `Foo` needs to create an instance of `MyHelper` without having any knowledge of `MyHelper's` dependencies:

```
public class Foo {
    private readonly IMyHelperFactory _factory;

    public Foo(IMyHelperFactory factory) {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    public void MethodThatCreatesMyHelper() {
        var instance = _factory.Create();
        // you now have a valid instance of `MyHelper`
    }
}
```

The last thing you would do is resolve `Foo` from your container (as long as you set it up):

```
var fooInstance = container.Resolve<Foo>();

fooInstance.MethodThatCreatesMyHelper();
```

And here is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/smith-neil/57abab47d69fc9846a72) of my example above. The point to take away is that `Foo` can create an instance `MyHelper` without having any knowledge of its dependencies.

Comment: But I have no instance of IService to pass in to the constructor.

Comment: That's what IoC is for. You shouldn't be creating the instance of `MyService`. I'll edit my answer with an example of how I handle this when I have a free minute.

Comment: @hurtchin - See my edit. Apologies for the super late response.

Comment: I still don't feel factory pattern is necessary in this case. I think Unity container itself should be enough to handle the dependency injection. But the other answer just seems not answering anything.

Comment: You can pass the container around. Look into the service locator vs composition root pattern. I prefer not to go with service locator because then you're dependent on the container all over the place.

Answer (score 1):

One technique is to initialize `MyHelper` with an object that *builds* an `IService` object in the constructor. This can be as simple as a lambda expession:

```
public class MyHelper : IMyHelper
{
    private Func<IService> _serviceBuilderFunc;

    public MyHelper(Func<IService> serviceBuilderFunc)
    {
        _serviceBuilderFunc = serviceBuilderFunc;
    }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        var svc = _serviceBuilderFunc();
        svc.RunSomething();
    }
}
```

Then in your unity container configuration use the overload of `RegisterType()` to specify constructor parameters:

```
var serviceBuilderFunc = () => new MyService();
container.RegisterType<IMyHelper, MyHelper>(
    new InjectionConstructor(serviceBuilderFunc));
```